# Get ListItem ID using Sharepoint Search API

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

How to get List item ID using Search API .

I am getting below properties along with that I need to get  item id.

```
$keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("Created")
$keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("LastModifiedTime")
$keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("CreatedBy")
$keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("ModifiedBy")
```

I am retrieving all list items(list items and  documents) created by a user in sites and its subsites. This is  my query:

`$queryText="createdby:xxxxxx"`

How can i get listitem Id ?

Comment: you can try with adding `$keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("ListItemID")` and check

Comment: ListItemID property is also same for documents???

Comment: yes, its the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list item's ID resides in a managed property named `ListItemID`.

So, you can add that in your selectproperties and it will give you the list item's ID.

Just add the below line in your code along with your current selectproperties :

```
$keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("ListItemID")
```